# Augmenting matrix rows iteratively with answers

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to add a row to a matrix every time an iterative loop in MATLAB produces an answer from fsolve function.

Say, fsolve produces an answer 3 and 2 (2 elements), and then I want to add these into a 1x2 matrix.

After a second loop fsolve produces an answer 5 and 3 (2 new elements) and I want to add these to the old solution matrix but as a new row so that a new matrix is a 2x2 matrix.

and on and on.

any ideas?

Comment: You mean like this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/68614-iterate-fsolve-and-save-each-iterated-result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `end` to add an extra column to your matrix, so `A(:,end+1) = [x1; x2];` adds an extra column to the matrix A. This also works for rows of course.

Answer (score 1):

To augment:

Before the loop:

```
A = [];
```

In the loop, for example:

```
A = [A; 3 2];
```

A better way is to pre-allocate the array given you know how many times you gonna run the loop.

For example,

```
A = zeros(n,2);
A(i,:) = [3 2];
```